# Notetaking file-based system for Vim

Tags: vim

I'm looking actually for something similar to [Deft](http://jblevins.org/projects/deft/), only for Vim. Does anyone know of any with which he/she has had good experiences?

Answer (score 17):

Check out vim-notes: https://github.com/xolox/vim-notes

It's a fairly sophisticated, and yet simple, note-taking platform. It doesn't have Deft's incremental search etc (I've used Emacs, so I know the features), but therefore you can tag your notes very comfortably, use auto-complete and, of course, search through the files. (The search is Python-based and so somewhat faster than vim-grep).

Just like in Deft, your notes are stored in one folder.

BTW, I think I found it while struggling with the exact same question as yours -- having recently moved to Vim, I needed an alternative to Deft.

**UPDATE:** Also, you could check out the CtrlP plugin: https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim. An excellent tool that allows you to search *file names* incrementally. It's very fast, nicely customizable and pure vimscript (so no external dependencies are needed).

**Many months later:** Also, there's *unite.vim*, which might have some potential as "poor man's Notational Velocity in Vim". At least people appear to be using it to [replace both ctrlp.vim and ack.vim/grep.vim with one plugin](http://bling.github.io/blog/2013/06/02/unite-dot-vim-the-plugin-you-didnt-know-you-need/). Looks very interesting indeed.

**Even more later:** Now there's also *nvim*, a direct clone of Notational Velocity. Looks good but takes some time to get used to in my experience: https://github.com/cwoac/nvim‎

**Almost another year later:** *microViche* might also be of interest here. Not quite like Deft, but an one of a kind approach to note taking or writing in Vim in my opinion. Basically it lets you link lines/paragraphs in different files, display all these links as a map (cool!) and have all files simultaneously open. So you can browse your documents as if you had them open in a microfiche reader, "panning and zooming through text" as the author says, and writing many documents in parallel. He also has a screencast for the plugin. https://github.com/q335r49/microviche

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Your answer does not provide any information why or how the program can answer the question. Please [take a look at these suggestions on how to provide great software recommendations](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I've used StackOverflow for some time, so I should've known. However, I added some details.

Answer (score 2):

Like Deft, [vim-pad](https://github.com/vim-scripts/vim-pad) is modeled after Notational Velocity (which rocks, by the way). [simplenote](https://github.com/mrtazz/simplenote.vim) is somewhat similar but it's more "cloud-minded".

There are other scripts on vim.org but these ones are the closest, I think.

Comment: I've actually used vim-pad, but it had some issues with PATH and losing data on Windows platform (hmm, maybe I should've mentioned that I'm on Windows). I've notified the author about it, but some issues still remain. Simplenote I'll check out.

Comment: The idea of vim-pad looks good but it was very unreliable on first and second try. I re-downloaded it after I wrote my answer and it's just as unreliable as it was before: fails to open some pre-existing notes, opens others in the same window… A simple (and mapped) `:Explore ~/Dropbox/nv` is enough for me.

Comment: Ah, I see - that means not much progress was done in the meantime (that's one of the things I envy emacs users; they have fewer plugins in total, but the ones that are popular are generally better done). I'm currently using something similar to :e ... but I miss a good searching function done the right way.

Answer (score 0):

checkout notational-fzf-vim it's pretty similar to deft (also former emacs user).
If you feel more adventurous, you can build it yourself with telescope-nvim.

This is a similar fuzzy-finder like fzf, but way better customizable and extendable.